# SharePoint Workflow Iniation Form (need update)

Tags: designer-workflow

I have created a simple list workflow that sends a couple of emails to a submitter and then a reviewer.   I'm a newbie to SharePoint Designer 2010 and saw the Workflow Initiation Form and knew it was associated with the workflow because of the buttons.   I have not modified it.  But when I try to publish the workflow, I keep seeing that the form "needs update".   How do I update the form?  I tried opening the form and then saving to my desktop but I'm assuming that this might have to be saved back to SharePoint.  I've been looking at various references, but they're super generic in talking about workflows and the initiation form.   Any ideas on why I'm getting the error?  And also good references that explain this since I have never run into this before.

Comment: I don't know what to suggest in terms of a solution, but perhaps posting a picture would help other users to visualise what is going on